# Hictop prusa I3 clone - broken z axis right bracket bearing

Tags: diy-3d-printer

I was very excited to get my 3d printer but sadly I didn't realise I'd installed the z axis upside down. There's a plastic coupler that goes into the hole for the polished rods it broke then released 1 -2mm sized ball bearing all over my floor.

Is it possible to just replace that coupler thingy?

Or if I 3d print a replacement will it still need that coupler thingy?

[image]

[image]

The first picture is the one that spilled it's guts all over my kitchen floor.

The last image is an example of how it used to look like but on the left hand side. I know the image looks like it's the right but you can see a bit of the horizontal rods if look closely

Comment: Can you provide a picture of this part?  I imagine it's a linear bearing but a plastic one with ball bearings in it is not something I have seen.  Either way, you need a picture or better description of what it is and where exactly it fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "plastic coupler thingy" is actually a linear bearing, and it consists of a metal shell, and the metal balls roll between the smooth rod and this shell. The plastic part has a channel that guides the balls in a circle.

It would be best to replace the entire bearing (metal part+balls+plastic liner). It's probably either an LM8UU (most likely) or LM8LUU bearing.

3D Printing a new part will not give good results.